# Writing contents of an STL Map to output stream using ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap, ostream

I have a `map<string, int>` object and I want to use `ostream_iterator` to write the contents of it to the screen or a file. I have overloaded output operator (`operator<<`) so that it can be used to write objects of type `pair<const string, int>` to an output stream, but when I try to compile the code I get the following error message:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are
> ‘std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, int> >::ostream_type’ {aka
> ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘const std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, int>’)
> 207 |  *_M_stream << __value;

I ended up using `for_each` function to write the contents, but I was curious to find out if  there's a way to use the stream iterator to do the job.
Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
typedef map<string, int>::value_type map_value_type;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const map_value_type &value) {
  out << value.first << " " << value.second;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  map<string, int> m;

  // code to fill the map

  // The following works with no problem
  for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const map_value_type &val) { cout << val << endl; });

  // This line will not compile
  copy(m.begin(), m.end(), ostream_iterator<map_value_type>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Curiously, when I force the compiler to give the full type names of parameters used in the `operator<<` function above, they exactly match the types mentioned in the error message, but for some reason compiler does not recognize to use it. I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) with -std=gnu++17 flag, but Visual Studio compiler (cl.exe version 19.29.30140) will give the same error.

I have also tried the following for `operator<<` without any success:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const pair<string, int> &val);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const pair<const string, int> &val);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, pair<const string, int> &val);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, pair<string, int> val);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, pair<const string, int> val);

template <typename key, typename value>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const pair<key, value> &val) { ... }
```

All of the above mentioned functions work with the `for_each` approach, but none of them work with `ostream_iterator`.

What am I missing?!

Comment: I think I know why your overload is failing, but I hazard saying how to "fix" it (because reality is it is no fix at all; it's dreadful): shove your `operator <<` overload (the first one) into namespace `std`. Then forget I ever suggested it.

Comment: Ugh...  until such time as someone a helluvalot more versed in the standard says it is OK to shove *that*... thing... into namespace `std`, no, it really didn't. There aren't many places where stuffing into `std` is ok (hash specializations would be one), and I cannot say this is one of them. If history has taught us anything, until you're sure, don't f'k with the standard. Figured it would work, but I still wouldn't pursue it without better confirmation than my gut. A man's gotta know his limitations.

Comment: @WhozCraig Definitively not allowed. But there isn't really any other way to overload `operator<<` for the containers consistently for all uses.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand what you're saying. I'd probably stick to the `for_each` approach. But it's good to finally get it to work. It was killing me that my overload wasn't working even though it seemed to be correct.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, I think so too. The warnings and suggestions [from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) basically say as much, and in fact their first example all-but solidifies that, as it is very close to the same concept being used here: an operator overload for a specific `std::pair`.  @cyrus, I wouldn't use `for-each` anyway, I'd just use ranged-for: `for (auto const& pr : m)`. Really saves on the typing.

Comment: @WhozCraig I totally agree with you. I just wanted the answer for a homework assignment, because it explicitly forbids using any `for` loops in the solution.

Comment: Wow. Lame. Because you know, those engineers can't be trusted with those fancy for-loops, but they can happily use a `for_each` construct that is so outdated no one actually uses it anymore. Ain't academia grand. Man.. good luck in there. Of course, you could also use a `while` loop, or perhaps a `do-while`, or maybe recursion. lolz. anything but sensibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ostream_iterator` uses `<<` internally.

When it is instantiated for a type, `<<` will find `operator<<` overloads only via argument-dependent lookup from the point of instantiation, not via normal unqualified name lookup.

For type `pair<const string, int>` (the element type of `map<string, int>`) the namespace considered for argument-dependent lookup is only `::std`, because both `pair` and `string` are defined in it. Your overload in the global namespace will not be considered.

If you had a type like `pair<MyClass, int>`, where `MyClass` is a class you defined yourself at global scope, the overload would work, because then the global namespace scope would be part of argument dependent lookup as associated namespace of the template argument `MyClass`.

The version using a lambda works because it does normal unqualified lookup from the point of definition of the lambda as well, which finds the overload in the global namespace.

Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, there is no standard-conform way to overload `operator<<` for a standard library container specialization which doesn't depend on a custom type, so that it will be found via ADL e.g. by `std::ostream_iterator`.

Standard-conform is the issue, since the standard forbids adding overloads of `operator<<` to namespace `std`, which otherwise would technically solve the issue.